# Mime type error when adding external js to Vue CLI

Tags: webpack, mime-types, vue-cli

I’m trying to add an external JS or CSS file to the Vue CLI
I have installed Bootstrap Vue with Webpack Simple

So I’m trying to add a simple JS file containing a simple array to the index.html. As far as I understood, these kind of resources should be placed within the static (not present by default in Webpack simple) or the assets folder. As a result, I always get the same 2 errors.

GET http://localhost:8080/assets/settings.js 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/assets/settings.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

The only way to get rid of the errors is to change the mime type to text/html, but then javascript is no longer interpreted by the browser.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

I fixed such error manually, by modification of the paths at the `dist/index.html` file:

Initial path:

```
src=/js/app.96a55d06.js
```

Modified path (dot added to the beginning of the string):

```
src=./js/app.96a55d06.js
```

Such procedure was repeated for both `.css` and `.js` imports

**Second solution(better)**

1. Run `npm run build`, where build is defined as `vue-cli-service build`
2. Make some kind of server: `python3 -m http.server`. Note, that it should be done inside the `dist` folder (folder with your build)